# Editing PhotoShop smart objects using Node

Tags: node.js, npm, psd

I have some photoshop files. They have smartobjects connected to specific layer named "smart_object" and want to replace particular images in the smart object programmatically using node.
Any idea if this can be done through node?

Thanks.

I have tried to find npm package for this. But didn't find.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: These psd files include specific layer named "mm_img" connected to psb file.
I want to change this psb file.